# knockout replace the binded model

Tags: knockout.js

I have a modal dialog to add new models and after a successful ajax submit I want to be able to type in a new model. So my logic was like this:

Button for new model -> set the editViewModel to a new model instance -> submit button -> after successful submit set the editviewModel to a new model

```
function model() {
    this.name = ko.observable("");
}

var myViewModel = new model();
myViewModel.name("Name 1");
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('foo'));

function newViewModel() {
    myViewModel = new model();
    myViewModel.name("NewName");
    //ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('foo'));
}​
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56gkz/

To get that working I have to re-apply the binding after changing the editViewModel to the new model instance.
So is it the right way to apply the binding again or is there a better solution to handle that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you would want to create an overall view model that you call applyBindings on once and then include an observable that you use to swap in and out your models to edit.  Then, in your markup you can use the `with` binding to bind a section of markup against the current value of that observable.

The JS code might look like:

```
function Model(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

function RootViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.selectedModel = ko.observable();
    this.models = ko.observableArray();

    this.createModel = function() {
        self.selectedModel(new Model("New Name"));
    };

    this.acceptModel = function(model) {
        self.models.push(model);
        self.selectedModel(null);
    };      

    //initialize with a model to start
    this.createModel();       
};


ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());​
```

The markup like:

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedModel">
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
    <button data-bind="click: $root.acceptModel">Accept</button>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: createModel">New Model</button>

<hr/>

<ul data-bind="foreach: models">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RWYL6/

Comment: In my real application I load the edit dialog by ajax so that i have two different view models but the missing part was just that I could make the whole editModel an observable to get the changes :)